# Pronouns from the Final Empire

Tags: pronouns

> Blue lines suddenly appeared before her— one end of each pointing at her chest, the other disappearing into the mists. Vin immediately jumped to the side, dodging as a pair of coins shot past in the night air, leaving trails in the mist. She flared pewter, landing on the cobbled street beside the wall . Her tin-enhanced ears picked out a scraping sound; then **a dark form** shot into the sky, a few blue lines pointing to **(1)his** coin pouch.
>
> Vin dropped a coin and threw herself into the air after her opponent. **(2)They** soared for a moment, flying over the grounds of some unsuspecting nobleman. Vin’s opponent suddenly changed course in the air, jerking toward the mansion itself. Vin followed, letting go of the coin below her, instead burning iron and Pulling on one of the mansion’s window latches.
>
> Her opponent hit first, and she heard a thud as he ran into the side of the building. He was off a second later."

As a non-English speaker who is not accustomed to pronouns, I get in trouble whenever I come across them.

Am I right in saying:

1. *his* indicates "a dark form"?
2. *they* indicates "Vin and a dark form"?

Comment: Which book are you quoting from?

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? The extract assigns a gender to the form (likely because physical form can indicate gender), and yes the 'they' represents her and the form (it could represent the coin too, however having read the book, the function of push would send the coin in the opposite direction rather than 'with' her).

Comment: In 1, *his* refers to the coin pouch. You can tell because it is the next thing in the sentence after the possessive. In 2, *they* refers to Vin and "her opponent" (whoever that is); you can tell because it comes right after the sentence where the two are introduced.

Comment: @nickson104 Thank you for your answer. My question is "What do pronouns indicate?"

Comment: @MattE.Эллен: From the title of the thread I gathered it was from Final Empire. Here: https://books.google.com/books?id=t_ZYYXZq4RgC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=Blue+lines+suddenly+appeared+before+her—+one+end+of+each+pointing+at+her+chest,+the+other+disappearing+into+the+mists.&source=bl&ots=X0dj-6_d9u&sig=ZHqg8anLOyHmk_tWIx9IWHb5bpE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qJ2jVceEE4eZgwT1oJToBw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Robusto Thank you for your answer. If "(2)they" refers to Vin and 'her opponent', doesn't "(1)his" refer to "a dark form"(I think of "a dark form" as "her opponent")?

Comment: @Matt E. Эллен Thank you for your correcting my awkward sentenses. Is this sentense correct?

Comment: The dark form is probably her opponent, but the reference to *his* absolutely means the coin pouch. The "few blue lines pointing to his coin pouch" is hard to fathom in its entirety, but is almost certainly referring to "the dark form" that shot up into the sky. This is not particularly good writing, btw.

Answer (score 1):

It's just as you've said:

1. *his* is referring to the **dark form** (the owner of the coin pouch, and Vin's opponent).
2. *they* is referring to *Vin and her opponent*.